# Dgrid 0.4 and dstore: update row in UI without put request

Tags: dojo, dgrid, dstore

In Dgrid 0.3.16 I was using an Observable store and when my data in the store was changed I called the store notify function. (not 'put' because I need only an UI update, this is a specific case)

```
store.notify(object, existingId);
```

I have now upgraded Dgrid to version 0.4 and I'm using 'dstore' as the store. The store is created like this:

```
        var store = new declare([ Rest, SimpleQuery, Trackable, Cache, TreeStore ])(lang.mixin({
            target:"/ac/api?fetchview",
            idProperty:"$uniqueid", 
            useRangeHeaders: true
        }, config));

        store.getRootCollection = function (parent, options) {
            return this.root.filter({parent: parent.$position},options);
        };

        store.getChildren = function (parent, options) {
            return this.root.filter({parent: parent.$position},options);
        };

        store.mayHaveChildren = function (item) {
            return item.$iscategory;
        };

        this.collection = store;
```

How do I notify the store when one row is changed without calling 'put'? I need dGrid to re-render the row.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

dstore follows a model more similar to typical event-driven approaches with `on` and `emit` methods.  dstore supports `add`, `update` and `delete` events - the first two expect an object with a `target` property referencing the item; the `delete` event expects an object with an `id` property referencing the item's identity.

So to notify of an updated item, call `store.emit('update', { target: updatedItem })`.

The `emit` method is documented under [Store methods](https://github.com/SitePen/dstore/blob/v1.0.2/docs/Store.md#method-summary), and the types of events are further enumerated in the [Collection documentation](https://github.com/SitePen/dstore/blob/v1.0.2/docs/Collection.md#ontype-listener).

Comment: Thanks, this works but when my item is a child in a tree parent than the item is updated at the wrong position. It will move before the first child of the current tree parent. How can I keep the current position of the updated item?

Comment: It should be possible to preserve order - e.g. editing and saving children works in the [Tree test page](http://dgrid.io/js/dgrid/test/Tree.html).  If you can provide more details on your specific case (e.g. what store modules you're using) it might make sense to open another question for that.

Comment: I removed my previous comment. The problem was that I was using these mixins in my store: Rest, Trackable, TreeStore, SimpleQuery. As soon as I removed "SimpleQuery", all items where correctly restored in their original place after an store.emit('update'... Currently I do not need "SimpleQuery" but why this would happen, I really don't know.